# Tracking player Score in Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine

I am looking for guidelines for my project. I am new to Unity/C#-game development overall. In my game, player makes choices and each choice has scores associated with it. How can I store all those stores ? Should I create a SQlite database for choices? And also keep track of the progress, where the player is at, so it does not start from the beginning.

Can you please point me towards the direction? Thank you.

V

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A database is great for highly relational data that needs to be sifted through. It's a heavy option and although it may solve the problem it might not be the best fit.

Checkout this tutorial: https://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/topics/scripting/persistence-saving-and-loading-data

Comment: Thank you Sir/Madam!. I'll take a look.